# Reading the terminal answerback string into a variable

Tags: terminal, xterm, terminal-emulator

Using *bash*, how can I read the terminal answerback into a variable w/o user interaction? The following one-liner still requires <kbd>Enter</kbd> to be pressed once:

```bash
echo -ne '\005' && read -s && echo ${REPLY}
```

Also, how can I configure *Xterm* to send something meaningful in response to `^E`? So far the only terminal emulator I've seen sending any answerback is *PuTTY*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answerback string is configurable in xterm using the [`answerbackString`](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:answerbackString) resource.  That resource was added in [1998](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_90).  Initially returning "xterm", since [1999](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_101) it defaults to an empty string because some users noticed the potential for abuse of control sequences which might send an unexpected command to the computer.

Other terminals may return an empty string always (konsole, mlterm, vte). But rxvt (and rxvt-unicode) return an unexpected response: the device attributes response for VT102 (an escape sequence).  [PuTTY returns "PuTTY"](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.67/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-answerback) (probably due to early influence by xterm).

In a quick check, Linux console displays an "a" (probably a bug).

Because the original VT100 provided this as a setup/configurable feature, that would have been limited to *printable* characters.  For that reason, rxvt/urxvt's response is unexpected.  The manual page makes an obscure comment about this:

> **`answerbackString`**: *string*
>   Specify the reply rxvt-unicode sends to the shell when an ENQ
>   (control-E) character is passed through. It may contain escape
>   values as described in the entry on **`keysym`** following.

(the promised description is absent).

Because the length of the answerback string is unknown, an application that reads it must allow for waiting (in case the characters arrive in more than one read operation).  There is of course the ksh/bash-specific `TMOUT` feature which can help with shell-scripting, along with the `-t` option for the `read` command.  For general use, I avoid that, using `stty`, e.g., (see [`dynamic.sh`](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/xterm-snapshots/blob/master/vttests/dynamic.sh#L62)):

```
stty raw -echo min 0 time 5
```

to temporarily set the terminal so that a `read` will timeout in 0.5 seconds, and allow it to return without reading any characters.  To see how the settings are saved/restored, it helps to read the script.

Further reading:

- the [`vttests`](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/xterm-snapshots/tree/master/vttests) scripts in `xterm`, many of which read terminal response strings.
- [**`stty`** - set the options for a terminal](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/stty.html) (POSIX)
- [**`read`** - read a line from standard input](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html) (POSIX)

Comment: Terminal needs to be reset back to normal state once the answerback is read, via `stty cooked`. The complete command line would then be `stty raw min 0 time 5; echo -ne '\005' && read -s; stty cooked; echo -n "${REPLY}"`. This produces exactly the same result as the "nibbling-on-bytes" approach suggested by [thrig](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/128228/thrig).

Answer (score 2):

Even with a timeout and (some) number of characters to be read it appears `bash` (`version 4.2.46(1)-release`) may not save the `REPLY`, here by issuing the "Report Cursor Position" control sequence, first with a newline entered, and second waiting for the timeout:

```
$ echo -ne '\033[6n' && read -n 16 -s -t 3; echo -n $REPLY | xxd
0000000: 1b5b 3234 3b31 52                        .[24;1R
$ echo -ne '\033[6n' && read -n 16 -s -t 3; echo -n $REPLY | xxd
$
```

The problem here is that `-n` is larger than the number of bytes returned; if `-n` is instead exactly the right size or smaller, the response will be read without input (or a timeout) being necessary. If you know a final unique character of the response string, you can get a response by splitting "lines" by that character; for the report character position prompt that delimiter could be taken to be `R`:

```
$ echo -ne '\033[6n' && read -n 999 -d R -s; echo -n $REPLY | xxd
0000000: 1b5b 3234 3b31                           .[24;1
$
```

Given unknown input of unknown length, you'd have to either file a bug against `bash`, or perhaps nibble on bytes one by tedious one until the timeout triggers:

```
$ out="got "; echo -ne '\033[6n'; while read -n 1 -s -t 1; do out="$out$REPLY"; done
$ echo -n $out | xxd
0000000: 676f 7420 1b5b 3234 3b31 52              got .[24;1R
$
```

For the <kbd>control+e</kbd> thing I suppose [a terminal could send something back](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html), but would have to be configured to do so:

```
ENQ       Return Terminal Status (Ctrl-E).  Default response is an empty
          string, but may be overridden by a resource answerbackString.
```

Comment: I don't think this is bash only because I'm having the same problem trying to read this in python.  I don't know how many bytes to read.  If guess less it reads that part, but over and it hangs, even with a select timeout.